# javascript return false form onclick not working

Tags: javascript

I've done this a million times.  Return false from an onclick to prevent the button from running.  Yet for some reason, this one button in this one form  on this one page...it ignores it.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return false;" 
     value="Copy To" name="btnCopy" id="btnCopy9">
```

I even took the javascript function out of it, so it just literally returns false on it's own.  Yet, this button is submitting the form.  I can't stop it.  Why might this be?  Any ideas?

I don't particularly see anything peculiar about this button.  I'm hoping it's staring me in the face and I am just not seeing it.

Comment: Why not <form onsubmit="return false" >

Comment: are you need type attribute??

Answer (score 0):

```
type="submit"
```

That's why it's submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to submit the form then why are you using the submit type .
you can simply use `type="button"` and call onClick method on it according to your need

```
 <input type="button" value="Copy To" name="btnCopy" id="btnCopy9">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your event bindings in separate JS and not rely on evaluation of JS strings inside of attributes.
In this case, you probably aren't preventing the `onsubmit` from running, only the click handler.

Do something like

```
var form = document.getElementById('yourFormId');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```